# Datadog tracing: Can I add a span to multiple traces?

Tags: datadog, distributed-tracing, data-tracing

Is there a way to add a span to multiple traces in Datadog tracing?

Our service receives orders that are batched into a transaction and then the transaction is processed. Each received order comes with its own trace-id. When processing the transaction I would like to add the processing span to each of those trace-ids.

```
order-1 \
order-2 | ----> batch A
order-3 /

order-4 \
order-5 | ----> batch B
order-6 /
```

In case this is relevant: the project is coded in python 3

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding tags to the spans than contain the shared key. I think this will be the easiest way to perform the queries you like while keeping the logical flow of the traces. Check out the docs on [custom span tags](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/guide/add_span_md_and_graph_it/#instrument-your-code-with-custom-span-tags).